# My favourite food is/are

Tags: word-choice

If I am talking about a food which has a plural form but the word "food" is in singular should I use a plural or a singular verb or should I in this case use both words in plural?

1."My favourite food is pizza."

2."My favourite food are dumplings."

3."My favourite foods are dumplings."

4. "My favourite food is dumplings."

5."My favourite foods are dumplings."

Comment: #3 and #5 are the same sentence....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the singular conjugation **is**. You are describing a single concept:

> My favorite food **is** pizza.
> My favorite food **is** dumplings.
> My favorite food **is** [chicken and waffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_and_waffles).

In all of the examples the food in question is a single *dish*, a singular *concept*. You could substitute the word "meal" or "dish" instead of "food" without changing any other part of the sentence.

Only use **are** if you are describing two distinct foods:

> My favorite foods **are** pizza and dumplings.

Comment: Good answer. If you say 'favorite foods are chicken and waffles' both those dishes are (two of) your favorite dishes. If you say 'favorite food is chicken and waffles' your favorite food is both of these together as one dish.

Comment: But if you reverse your statements, **Dumplings are my favourite food.** The verb follows the subject, whether singular or plural.